# Switching styles in CSS, under the specified conditions laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I need to specify my styles under certain conditions

```
<div class="flex-container">
                @foreach($topServers as $server)
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            @foreach($guilds as $guild)
                                @if($server->id == $guild->id)
                                    <img class="col-md-auto avatar" src="..." alt="">
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Provided that `$server->premium >= 1`, you need to specify the `"border-color:gold"` styles in the `div class="flex-item"`

And I absolutely do not understand how to implement it, thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a ternary to add a style.

```
<div class="flex-item" {{ $server->premium >= 1 ? 'style="border-color:gold"' : '' }}>
```

Comment: Or even better ... use a class (I know OP asked for style).

Comment: @F.Müller Yep, either way it will work. For a class, the ternary would just need to be moved inside of the class attribute